# Nesting loop within a block in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a helper module to generate an array hash data, which is something like:

```
[{:date => d, :total_amount => 31, :first_category => 1, :second_category => 2,...},
 {:date => d+1, :total_amount => 31, :first_category => 1, :second_category => 2,...}]
```

So I make the method like:

```
def records_chart_data(category = nil, start = 3.weeks.ago)
  total_by_day = Record.total_grouped_by_day(start)
  category_sum_by_day = Record.sum_of_category_by_day(start)

  (start.to_date..Time.zone.today).map do |date|
    {
      :date  => date,
      :total_amount => total_by_day[date].try(:first).try(:total_amount) || 0,
      Category.find(1).title => category_sum_by_day[0][date].try(:first).try(:total_amount) || 0,
      Category.find(2).title => category_sum_by_day[1][date].try(:first).try(:total_amount) || 0,
      Category.find(3).title => category_sum_by_day[2][date].try(:first).try(:total_amount) || 0,
    }
  end
end
```

Since the Category will always change, I try to use loop in this method like:

```
def records_chart_data(category = nil, start = 3.weeks.ago)
  total_by_day = Record.total_grouped_by_day(start)
  category_sum_by_day = Record.sum_of_category_by_day(start)

  (start.to_date..Time.zone.today).map do |date|
    {
      :date  => date,
      Category.all.each_with_index do |category, index|             
        category.title => category_sum_by_day[index][date].try(:first).try(:total_amount) || 0,
      end
      :total_amount => total_by_day[date].try(:first).try(:total_amount) || 0
    }
  end
end
```

But ruby alerts me with an error:

```
/Users/tsu/Code/CashNotes/app/helpers/records_helper.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end
      category.title => category_sum_by_day[index][d...
```

Why does it say `expecting keyword_end`, and how should I fix it?

---

The method `category_sum_by_day` it calls looks like:

```
def self.sum_of_category_by_day(start)
  records = where(date: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.today)
  records = records.group('category_id, date(date)')
  records = records.select('category_id, date, sum(amount) as total_amount')
  records = records.group_by{ |r| r.category_id }
  records.map do |category_id, value|
    value.group_by {|r| r.date.to_date} 
  end
end
```

Or should I alter this method to generate a more friendly method for the helper above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Category.all.each_with_index do |category, index|             
  category.title => category_sum_by_day # ...snip!
end
```

Unfortunately, this piece of code does not adhere to Ruby's grammar. The problem is the body of the block. `x => y` is *not* an expression and the syntax requires bodies of blocks to be expressions.

If you want to generate a hash by one key-value pair at a time try the following combination of `Hash::[]`, `Array#flatten` and the splat operator (i.e. unary `*`):

```
Hash[*5.times.map { |i| [i * 3, - i * i] }.flatten]
```

As a result I'd rewrite the last expresion of `records_chart_data` more or less as follows

```
(start.to_date..Time.zone.today).map do |date|
  categories = Hash[*Category.all.each_with_index do |category, index|
    [ category.title, category_sum_by_day[...] ]
  end .flatten]

  { :date  => date,
    :total_amount => total_by_day[date].try(:first).try(:total_amount) || 0
  }.merge categories
end
```

If you consider it unreadable you can do it in a less sophisticated way, i.e.:

```
(start.to_date..Time.zone.today).map do |date|
  hash = {
    :date  => date,
    :total_amount => total_by_day[date].try(:first).try(:total_amount) || 0
  }
  Category.all.each_with_index do |category, index|
    hash[category.title] = category_sum_by_day[...]
  end
  hash
end
```

Another idea is to use `Array#reduce` and adopt a more functional approach.

```
(start.to_date..Time.zone.today).map do |date|
  Category.all.each_with_index.reduce({
    :date  => date,
    :total_amount => total_by_day[date].try(:first).try(:total_amount) || 0
  }) do |hash, (category, index)|
    hash.merge category.title => category_sum_by_day[...]
  end
  hash
end
```